# Python discrete differentiation

Tags: python, differentiation

I am reading in a file with two columns of numerical data. Let the first column be 'x', and the second column be 'y'.

The data in 'x' is not uniformly spaced. That is, it goes something like this:

2.4 2.6 2.7 3.0 3.2 3.5 ...

The data is finite obviously. It has an initial and a final value.

I need to find "discontinuities" in this data. I want to do this my differentiating the data: dy/dx

I've done a search, but all the differentiation answers I found involve an analytical function, such as y=x**2+1

My data is discrete and does not fit an analytical function. I need to find the derivative at each value of 'x' over this data, keeping in mind that 'x' is not evenly spaced.

So, suppose I have read in the data from my data file, and stored them in variables 'x' and 'y'.

Now I want dy/dx, and I want to plot dy/dx vs x.

What can I "import" that will do this derivative? Or am I going to have to write the algorithm myself?

Comment: First, what you attempted so far?  Please post your code.  This really depends on what you mean by a discontinuity.  How are you defining that?  Do you just want to determine by eye if a jump in the derivative exists from the plot?

Comment: I haven't tried anything, because all the differentiation routines that I found in SciPy and other packages required a uniform step size = h.

My step size is not uniform, as I originally stated.

I just need something to do the differentiation of the date. "Why" is not important.

Comment: You need to define what is a discontinuity. Then you can think how to do the check - most likely with a not too difficult hand written code.

Comment: That's not important. I just want to do the derivative.

Answer (score 0):

I would write [the algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_derivative) yourself.  There isn't a built-in import that does this.  Here's some code to use as a starting point:

```
>>> xarr = [2.4, 2.6, 2.7, 3.0, 3.2, 3.5, 3.8, 4.1, 5.3]
>>> yarr = [10, 12, 18, 20, 22, 27, 30, 32, 36]
>>> [(y2-y0)/(x2-x0) for x2, x0, y2, y0 in zip(xarr[2:], xarr, yarr[2:], yarr)]
[26.666666666666643, 20.000000000000004, 8.0, 
 14.0, 13.333333333333341, 8.333333333333337, 4.0]
```

You can refine the approximations by weighting each side according to the distance from the center of three points, but this likely isn't necessary if all you're doing is looking for discontinuities.

Comment: Can I assign that last line to a variable? Such as

dy=[(y2-y0)/(x2-x0) for x2, x0, y2, y0 in zip(xarr[2:], xarr, yarr[2:], yarr)]

Comment: That would work.  The values correspond to derivative estimates for ``xarr[1:-1]``.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `zip(xarr[1:], xarr, yarr[1:], yarr)`? Right now, you're comparing values that are two indices apart, instead of one.

Comment: @Junuxx That was on purpose.  There are better numeric properties if you use index forward and one index back. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_derivative

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple algorithm which breaks my array into smaller arrays of 3 points. Then fit a 2nd order function through those three points, take its derivative, and calculate the value at the middle point. For the end points, I only use two values.

It's a bit messy. And I know there are more efficient ways to do the loop. Here is what I did:

```
dydx=[]

for i in range(len(x)):
    if i==0:
        dx=x[i:i+2]
        dy=y[i:i+2]
        order=1
    elif i==len(x)-1:
        dx=x[i-1:i+1]
        dy=y[i-1:i+1]
        order=1
    else:
        dx=x[i-1:i+2]
        dy=y[i-1:i+2]
        order=2
    z=np.polyfit(dx,dy,len(dx)-1)
    f=np.poly1d(z)
    df=np.polyder(f)
    dydx.append(float(df(x[i])))
dydx=np.array(dydx)
```

Any suggestions on cleaning this loop up in a way that eliminates the if-elif statements?